# Not able to call javascript function in dynamically generated HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not able to call the javascript function with parameter in dynamically generated HTML code.

The same function gets called successfully when I don't pass any parameter, but with parameters the function call fails. Not sure whether it is a syntax error.

below is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>

            <p>Click the button to call a function with arguments</p>
            <button onclick="myFunction('Harry Potter','Wizard')">Try it</button>

            <script>
            function myFunction(name,job) {
                var name="prasad";
                var str='<a href="#" onclick="javascript: fun('+name+')">link</a>';
                document.write(str);
            };

            function fun(id1) {
                alert("fun menthod "+id1);
            }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

If I don't pass the parameter it gets called successfully.

Comment: Usually when you cannot call JS from within HTML it means there is a JS error, open the JS console and look

Comment: BTW: It works on JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=wHI6Ep7zgl

Comment: I tried your code and it's working... (Good practice : do not declare the same variable twice : name. It was already declared as a param. So, just affect the new value without the "var" tag.)

Comment: You should use innerHTML property instead document.write(). 
Check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/NU2yF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="next">
<p>Click the button to call a function with arguments</p>
<button onclick="myFunction('Harry Potter','Wizard')">Try it</button>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction(name,job)
{
var a='"';
a=a+name+a;
var str="<a href='#' onclick='fun("+a+")'>link</a>";
document.getElementById('next').innerHTML=str;
}
function fun(id1)
{
alert("fun menthod "+id1);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you all for you prompt response

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line, because the variable name is same as the parameter name

```
var name="prasad";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:     `var name="prasad";` you change the value of the 'name' parameter maybe this is your problem. Try deleting this line and see the output.

Answer (score 0):

change name to:

```
var name="'prasad'";
```

I'm seeing syntax error in JS Console otherwise.